# What features should I consider when evaluating a hammock-tent hybrid?

Tags: camping, tents, wild-camping, hammock, tarp-tents

I have seen a number of hammock posts which replace the traditional tent structure by incorporating a waterproof bivi as top cover.

Have any Outdoors.SE used a system of that description and can they make any recommendations of features I should be looking for?

Comment: In what circumstances do you want to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hammock

- Can you lie flat in it?
- How large/heavy is it?
- Footbox?
- Color (stealth camping?)

Suspension

- How easy is it to adjust?
- Can you adjust your hammock to different sags?  Do you always want to have the same amount of sag?
- What is the furthest distance between trees that your suspension can accommodate?  This will depend on

  - How much stretch there is in the suspension
  - If you have a structural ridgeline that allow you to get the amount of sag you want while running your ropes closer to horizontal
- If it rains will water run down your suspension onto your hammock?  (Hint - drip lines).
- Weight/size

Insulation

- Choices are typically: Underquilt or sleeping pad for the bottom, sleeping bag or top quilt for the top.
- Do you want to sleep on the ground if you can't find suitable trees?
- Typical insulation questions and tradeoffs such as: weight, what temperature range are you targeting?

Shelter:

- Do you want to use the shelter for other things or sleeping, ie cooking, etc.
- Small & light
- Shape?

Bug Protection:

- How should it attach to the hammock?

Integrated system or separate system?

- You can sometimes get systems that include insulation/bug netting/hammock in one system.
- Benefits: Lower cost, comparability
- Drawbacks: Harder to use pieces independently (day in the park).